# Confused about a word in Quran

Tags: quran

In Quran there is a word often repeated and it is "bani-israeel". What does this word refers to. Does it refer to the earlier people to whom Quran was revealed first or something else?

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/what-is-difference-of-jews-and-bani-israeel-in-quran  check this question.

Comment: Dear user14284, @QaisarSatti mentioned a related link correctly. then that's why your question may be would be closed. Otherwise, you asked it nicely and even it could be my question too. Therefore you'd better to refer to the mentioned link. Good luck mate.

Answer (score 1):

All praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His Family and Compmanions.

**Bani-Israil** means *Children of Israil* and **Israil** is a hebrew word ,,Word **"Isra"** refers to **Man** or **Slave**   and Word **"il"** in Isra-il is from **"ilah"** which refers to  **God or Allah Swt**,, meaning Man or Slave of Allah Swt and this was Title for Prophet Yaqub (Jacob)peace be upon him.He was the son of Prophet Ishaq(Isaac) and Prophet Ishaq pbuh was son of prophet Ibrahim (Abraham) pbuh and Sarah pbuh,whereas Prophet Ismail pbuh was son Of Ibrahim and Hajrah peace be upon them.So Bani Israil refers to Children of Yaqub and Bani Ismail refers to Children of Ismail pbuh.

Bani Israil has around 4000 Prophets like Yusuf ,Musa ,Dawd, Suleman ,Isa peace be upon all and in Bani Ismail is the only Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him.Bani Israil are blessed with Torah ,Zabur ,Injil with lots of higher status and values .Bani Israil were earlier dignified By Allah swt and now After them Ummah of Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him are more exalted.Quran was revealed to Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him so earlier holy books are adulterated or modified but Quran is preserved by Allah swt.

**"O Children of Israel, remember My favor that I have bestowed upon you and that I preferred you over the worlds"**.[Quran 2:47](http://quran.com/2/47) and [2:122](http://quran.com/2/122)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: You would be interested this answer in the page mapped as duplicate i.e. [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/what-is-difference-of-jews-and-bani-israeel-in-quran)

Answer (score 0):

Qur'an was reveal to our Prophet Muhammed SAW and his Ummah... Bani israel were the Ummah of Musa AS.... They were said to be among the best people of their time, Allah chose Bani Israel among the people of their time bani Israel (children of Israel) they were poor and slaves and labourers. And Taurah was sent unto them!