# Bani Israel and Christians

Tags: quran, tafseer, bani-israel, prophet-yaqub

I know that all Jews are Bani Israel but not all Bani Israel are Jews. Are Christians Bani Israel as well, do they descend from Prophet Israel (AS)? This is not a duplicate, the answer to this question is not in any of the other articles, I want to know if Christians are also Bani Israel, I'm not asking about the difference between Jews and Bani Israel. Just please answer this question it's not a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference of "Jews" and "Bani Israeel" in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/what-is-difference-of-jews-and-bani-israeel-in-quran)

Comment: I wonder if this question belongs to Islam SE at all.

Answer (score 1):

*'All'* of the Christians are **not** Bani Israel, just like all of the Muslims are not Bani Ishmael or even Arab, because several gentiles converted to Christianity at the hands of the disciples of Jesus and then the adoption of the religion by the Roman Empire, and later the preaching of Christian missionaries.

Bani Israel is a lineage and not a religion. Statistically speaking only a small minority of the present Christian population would belong to the Bani Israel.

Answer (score 0):

BANI ISRAEL

The Arabic word “إِسْرَائِيلَ” is a combination of two-word Isra and El. Isra has root word “ا س ر” and from this root word it means prisoner and El is God so we can translate Israel as Prisoner of God or Prisoned for God.
If we change this word in Arabic it will become “ISRA ULLAH” meaning “Prisoner of Allah”.

We know that Allah SWT in His divine wisdom made his prophet Yusuf PBUH to be prisoned several years in Egypt. So, in my humble opinion the “Israel” in Quran is referred to Prophet Yusuf PBUH and Bani Israel is a reference to children of Yusuf PBUH not children of Yaqoob PBUH.

There are some mind-boggling similarities and connections in the Quran in reference of Prophet Yusuf PBUH and Israel. There is only one Surah in Quran named Surah Yusuf and there is only one Surah by the name Surah Bani Israel. The individual person “Israel” named twice in Quran Surah Al Imran Ayat 93, Surah Maryam Ayat 58 and Prophet Yusuf PBUH name is also occurred twice in the Quran Surah Al Anam Ayat 84 and and Surah Ghafir (Momin) Ayat 34 besides Sura Yusuf and Aal e Yaqub is also appeared twice in glorious Quran Surah Yusuf Ayat 6 and Surah Maryam Ayat 6.
And the most important fact is that Surah Bani Israel has 111 Ayat and Surah Yusuf has 111 Ayat as well. So, Bani Israel means “Children of Yusuf”.

Today when we say “JEWS” or “YAHUD” it is understood as a group of people who are mainly from the progeny of Prophet Yaqub PBUH. But is it true or correct?

Allah SWT has used a few different words to describe people in the Story of Prophet Musa PBUH. Allah SWT used QOM E MUSA, ASBAAT, AAL E YAQUB, BANI ISRAEL and CHOSEN PEOPLE for these people. Do you think they all are the same and we can easily translate them as “JEWS” or “YAHUD”?

I have a detailed essay where I can prove from the glorious Quran that Allah SWT divided QOM E MUSA into 12 tribes (ASBAT) not Bani Israel. And AAl E YAQUB, BANI ISRAEL and CHOSEN PEOPLE are referred to as the Progeny of Prophet YUSUF PBUH which was one tribe among 12.

If you read the story of Prophet Musa PBUH which is in great detail in the Quran you won’t find the word YAHUD even a single time in this story. What does it mean? It means YAHUD were not part of that struggle and journey and they mixed up later with Bani Israel and other tribes.

I can prove from the Quran that YAHUD are progeny of Qom E Hud and they mixed up with Bani Israel when Talut was appointed as a king. Talut and his followers belonged to YAHUD meaning Qom e Hud. You will find all references of Yahud in the Quran after the timeline of Prophet Dawood PBUH and Prophet Sulaiman PBUH.

We know that Khazars or “ASHKANZI” converted to Judaism after almost 2 centuries of Prophet Muhammad PBUH and after revelation of Quran. So how can we say Yahud of Quran apply on Ashkanazi jews as well? We know they have nothing to do with Qom e Musa, Bani Israel or Yahud. They are progeny of Gog and Magog.

So today when we say “JEWS” it means a group of people who are comprises of or mix of mainly from the progeny of 11 sons of prophet Yaqub PBUH and Prophet Yusuf, Progeny of Qom e Hud and progeny of Gog and Magog and few others who converted to Judaism and they claim that they follow Prophet Musa PBUH. Today JEWS population in the world is around 15 million and I believe that the majority of them are from the progeny of Aad and from the progeny of Khazars, Gog and Magog. A very minor percentage among them belong to the progeny of 11 sons of prophet Yaqub PBUH and Prophet Yusuf PBUH.

They are classified as ASHKANZIE JEWS, SEPHARDIC JEWS, MIZRAHI JEWS and EITHOHOPIAN JEWS. They can further be divided according to the country they belong to and sect they following.

NASARAH AND CHRISTIANS

The word Nasarah of the Quran is often translated as Christians. Is it correct or right to do so? Because there are various types of Christians exists, like Catholic, protestant, Orthodox, Nazarene and some other offshoots of these. So what Allah SWT means by calling a people Nasarah in Quran.

NASARAH

The city where Prophet Esa PBUH lived, was existed before him and it was called in old Hebrew as Ne-cer , in classic Syriac “Nasarta” in Aramaic “Nasrath” in Hebrew Natzrat and in Arabic it is called An-Nasirah. Prophet Esa as we know is called Jesus of Nazreth and in Arabic he is also called “Esa An Nasiri”.

The Quran is in Arabic language so we have to see all the things mentioned in the Quran with the reference of Arabic language. Allah SWT did not give this name NASARAH to these people but Allah SWT called them in the Quran "from those of you who call yourself Nasarah". Surah Maida Ayat 14

وَمِنَ الَّذِينَ قَالُوا إِنَّا نَصَارَىٰ أَخَذْنَا مِيثَاقَهُمْ

And from those who say, “We are Nasarah,” We took their covenant.

Meaning Nasarah is not a divine or religious title, people would use to call it for themselves before the Quran was revealed. If we take Nasarah as “helpers” then Allah SWT has used this word for many people even the people of Madina are called “Ansar”. Can we translate here word “Ansar” as follower of Muhammad or as Muslim? They were Muslims and helpers of Prophet Muhammad PBUH in his early days and same applies on hawareen or apostles of Prophet Esa PBUH.

It is said that early followers of Prophet Esa PBUH who were Muslims of that time belonged to this town Nasirah or Nazereth. Initially Yahud and other people called them Nasarah in a derogatory sense. They were from Bani Israel and were Muslims of that time but they were very few in numbers and very weak as well so they did not resist to this name and accepted it as their identity.

So, in Divine wisdom Nasarah can mean “helpers” and can also mean “people who belong to Nasarah town.

CHRISTIANS

Roman were ruling this area near Jerusalem and when they saw some people associate themselves with Anointed one “Christ” they gave them a name “Christianitas” and eventually that word became Christians.

In the 4th century AD Romans accepted Christianity and then this word after passing through other European languages in English language gradually became “Christian” and People who were following Christ accepted it and now it is universally understood Christians as followers of Christ.

The Same European sometime call us Muslims as “Mohammeden” But by the blessing of Allah SWT we rejected it and still call ourselves Muslims. Had we accepted that term, today we would have been known as “Mohammden” and this would have been a kufr as to change the name that Allah SWT gave to this Ummat and we accept a name some other people gave to us. This is what happened to the followers of Prophet Esa PBUH and they accepted this name given by others and became or known as “Christians”.

Also, it is very interesting that Nazareth Israel who are Christians but they do not accept this Roman version of Christianity.

So Nasarh is applied only to early Christians of the first century. Their followers existed till the time of Prophet Muhammad PBUH. Like the Christian teachers of Salman Farsi, Christians from Narajan and Christians of Habsha may fall in this category of Nasarah. Even today the Nazareth Israel are Christian who follow the first century teaching of the apostle of Prophet Esa PBUH and they reject Roman Christianity.

Now as Khazars converted to Judaism in 8th century, they cannot fall into the category of Yahud, Progney of Yaqub PBUH or Bani Israel. Similarly, nations and people who converted to Roman or Orthodox Christianity in 4th century BCE and who changed the teachings of the first century apostles and Esa PBUH, they cannot be called Nasarah.

Today "Christians" means people who claim they are followers
of Christ and may belong to any part of the world.

But in today’s time any group of Christians who would want to come under the term Nasarah, they at least must go back to the teachings of the First century apostles who believed in virgin birth, who did not consider Prophet Esa PBUH as God, who did not believe in trinity, who followed the Sharia of Torah revealed on Prophet Musa PBUH not written by Rabbis, and then they may be called Nasarah.

For a detailed researched essay please contact

quranfehmi786@gmail.com